# Solving $3\sin x - \cos x = 2$ for $x \in [0, 2\pi)$

Tags: trigonometry

**Problem:**

Solve $$3\sin x - \cos x = 2, \ \ \  x \in [0, 2\pi)$$

**My attempt:**

I am able to solve it using Weierstrass substitutions and a good bit of patience, but the problem was given at an exam at a level where such substitutions are not part of the curriculum.

I've tried to find ways to rewrite the equation by using $\sin x / \cos x = \tan x$ which I expect is the "desired" method, but for some reason, my algebra is failing me, and I can't seem to eliminate the $\sin$ and $\cos$ terms.

I've tried squaring both sides, but given the coefficient on $\sin x$, I can't find a way to use that identity either.

So far I end up with $$9\sin^2x - 6\sin x\cos x + \cos^2x = 4$$

Any help appreciated!

Comment: If you write your calculations we can see where they failed.

Comment: @EmilioNovati - I added my brick wall as far as squaring both sides.

Comment: @mfl - Yeah, that's the part I'm stuck on. I end up with $9\sin^2x + \cos^2x$ which I don't think I can use.

Comment: Dividing by $\cos^2 x$ you have the equation in jameselmore answer.

Comment: @EmilioNovati - That's actually very clever. I like that method! However, imaginary numbers and hyperbolic trig-functions aren't curriculum at this level either. But jameselmore's answer seems pretty nice as is. Thanks!

Comment: Squaring both sides will work if you put $-\cos x=2-3\sin x$ and square. Another way is to write $(\sin x)(3/\sqrt{10})-\cos x(-1/\sqrt{10})=\frac{2}{\sqrt{10}}$ and use $\sin(x-\theta)=\sin x\cos\theta-\cos x\sin\theta$.

Comment: @Alec, See also : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/757497/how-to-solve-4-sin-theta-3-cos-theta-5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint to another possible way:

$$
3 \sin x -2= \cos x \Rightarrow 3 \sin x -2=\sqrt{1-\sin^2 x}
$$
squaring you have a second degree equation in $\sin x$. Also in this case be careful to extraneous solutions that can be introduced by squaring.

Comment: This is probably the best approach, in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks, ended up using this approach, but it was ugly as hell. I fumbled a bit, because I got $x \approx 0.363$ as a solution which was false, so I discarded it. But using $$\pi - x \approx 0.363$$ from $$\sin(x) = \sin(\pi-x)$$ ended up being a legitimate solution, which took me a while to realize.

Answer (score 5):

Another approach is to write: $$A \sin(x) + B \cos(x)=C$$ and then divide by $$\sqrt{A^2 + B^2}$$ to get:

$$\frac{A}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}\sin(x) + \frac{B}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}\cos(x) = \frac{C}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}$$

Since $$\left(\frac{A}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{B}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}\right)^2 = 1$$ there is a $\psi$ such that $$\cos(\psi) = \frac{A}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}} \text{ and } \sin(\psi) = \frac{B}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}.$$

Thus we have $$\cos(\psi)\sin(x) + \sin(\psi)\cos(x) = \frac{C}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}$$ and using the sum formula we find:

$$\sin(x+\psi) = \frac{C}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}.$$

---

In this case $A=3$ and $B=-1$ so $\sqrt{A^2+B^2} = \sqrt{10}$. Since $A > 0$ and $B < -1$, this means $\psi$ is in the third quadrant. Thus $\arctan(-1/3) = \psi$.

Finally this means $$\sin(x + \arctan(-1/3)) = 2/\sqrt{10}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
$$3\sin x - \cos x = 2 \implies 3\tan x - 1 = 2\sec x$$
$$9\tan^2x - 6\tan x + 1 = 4\sec^2x = 4(1 + \tan^2x)$$
$$5\tan^2x - 6\tan x - 3 = 0$$

Just need to be careful about any extraneous solutions

Answer (score 1):

If
$a \sin x + b \cos x = c
$,
divide by
$\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$
to get
$A \sin x + B \cos x = C$
where
$A^2+B^2 = 1$.

Choose $y$
so that
$A = \cos y$ and $B = \sin y$
(i.e., 
$\tan y = B/A$).

Then
$C
= \sin x \cos y + \cos x \sin y
= \sin(x+y)
$,
so
$x+y = \sin^{-1}(C)$
or
$x = \sin^{-1}(C)-y$
.

As is often the case,
nothing original here.

Answer (score 1):

When you arrive at
$$
9\sin^2x - 6\sin x\cos x + \cos^2x = 4
$$
just note that $4=4\sin^2x+4\cos^2x$ so you can rewrite your equation as
$$
5\sin^2x-6\sin x\cos x-3\cos^2x=0
$$
Since $\cos x=0$ is not a solution, divide by $\cos^2x$ and get
$$
5\tan^2x-6\tan x-3=0
$$
so
$$
\tan x=\frac{3\pm\sqrt{24}}{5}
$$

You need to exclude the extraneous solution, of course.

A different method that doesn't need $\tan(x/2)$ is to set $X=\cos x$, $Y=\sin x$ and transform the equation into
$$
\begin{cases}
3Y-X=2\\
X^2+Y^2=1
\end{cases}
$$
so $X=3Y-2$ and then
$$
(3Y-2)^2+Y^2=1
$$
so
$$
10Y^2-12Y+3=0
$$
which gives $Y=\dfrac{6\pm\sqrt{6}}{10}$ and $X=\dfrac{-2\pm\sqrt{6}}{10}$ (with the same choice of signs). Thus $\tan x=Y/X$ and so
$$
\tan x=\frac{3\pm2\sqrt{6}}{5}
$$
as it is easy to verify. Note that this method is guaranteed not to introduce extraneous solutions.