# Prove that type question of Trigonometric Identities

Tags: trigonometry

> If $3\sin A + 5\cos A = 5$, then prove that:
>      $$5\sin A + 3\cos A = ±3.$$

Comment: Please check the question for a possible sign typo.

Comment: This does not seem to be correct.

Comment: Presumably one is really intended to show that $5\sin A-3\cos A=\pm 3$.  
It is **not true** that $5\sin A+3\cos A$ is necessarily equal to $\pm 3$. Indeed only the trivial solutions $\cos A=0$ of $3\sin A+5\cos A=5$ satisfy the second equation. And $3\sin A+5\cos A=5$ has non-trivial solutions, for example $A=2\arctan(3/5)$.

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/757497/how-to-solve-4-sin-theta-3-cos-theta-5

Answer (score 1):

The question as stated seems to be ***incorrect***. Most likely it is asking for $$\color{blue}{5 \sin A} \color{red}{-} \color{blue}{3 \cos A}.$$
If such is the case then from the first equation if we divide throughout by $\sqrt{34}$, we get
$$\frac{3}{\sqrt{34}} \sin A + \frac{5}{\sqrt{34}} \cos A=\frac{5}{\sqrt{34}}.$$
Let $\sin \alpha=\frac{3}{\sqrt{34}}$, then we get
$$\cos(A-\alpha)=\frac{5}{\sqrt{34}}.$$
But then we also get
$$\cos(A-\alpha)=\frac{5}{\sqrt{34}}=\cos \alpha.$$
This implies that
$$A-\alpha = 2n \pi \pm \alpha, \qquad \text{ for } n \in \mathbb{Z}.$$
Thus 
$$A=2n \pi \qquad \text{ or } \qquad A=2n\pi+2\alpha.$$

Let $\color{blue}{5 \sin A} \color{red}{-} \color{blue}{3 \cos A}=x$.

1. If $A=2n \pi$, then $x=-3$.
2. If $A=2n\pi+2\alpha$, then $5 \sin A \color{red}{-} 3 \cos A=5 \sin 2\alpha \color{red}{-} 3 \cos 2\alpha$.

Using the values of $\sin \alpha$ and $\cos \alpha$, we get $x=3$.

Thus $x = \pm 3$.

**NOTE:** If the actual problem (with $+$ sign) stands as is then $x=-3$ or $x=\frac{99}{17}$.

Comment: Please answer accordingly I'm just 10th standard student

Comment: @AkshanshBhura I believe that all the steps I have shown should be within the reach of a 10th standard student from India (I am assuming you are from India). In case there is any step where you need more explanation then I will be happy to elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

HINT. Try squaring the first identity and then use $\sin^2A+\cos^2A=1$