# Finding Trignometric Equation

Tags: trigonometry

$$3\sin x + 4\cos x = 5$$ then the value of $\tan(x/2)$

I should get the answer as $1/3$ but my answer is $(5\sec x-4)/3$.

Can any one help me thanks in advance.

Comment: Am trying to to get the tanx from RHS... Can you give me the solution please?

Comment: Check out this youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ijsUvXPdMxE   This is what Euler88 is referring too

Comment: The way to proceed is almost in the question. Use the tangent half-angle substitution $t=\tan(\frac x2)$ just as Zhanxiong answered.

Comment: This is rather similar to: [How to solve $4\sin \theta +3\cos \theta = 5$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/757497)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$ and $3\sin x+4\cos x=5$ implies $\sin x=3/5$ and $\cos x=4/5$. So you can conclude.

Comment: @Hello, How have you concluded $\tan\dfrac x2$ from the answer?

Comment: Using that $\tan(x-y)=\frac{\tan(x)-\tan(y)}{1+\tan(x)\tan(y)}$. Change $y=x/2$ and conclude.

Answer (score 2):

Let $t = \tan(x/2)$, apply the celebrated formula:
$$\sin x = \frac{2\tan(x/2)}{1 + \tan^2(x/2)} = \frac{2t}{1 + t^2}, \quad \cos x = \frac{1 - \tan^2(x/2)}{1 + \tan^2(x/2)} = \frac{1 - t^2}{1 + t^2}.$$
Plug these back into the given equation, we have
$$\frac{6t}{1 + t^2} + \frac{4(1 - t^2)}{1 + t^2} = 5.$$

This is a standard quadratic formula, can you take it from here?

Comment: No am not able to get this.. Can you give me simple solution?

Comment: Then how about @Euler88 solution. It needs sharper observation though.

Comment: Yaa.. Now i have got from @Euler88 solution