# Determining the general solution for the trigonometric equation $ 5\cos(x)-12\sin (x) = 13 $

Tags: trigonometry

Given that
$$5\cos(x)-12\sin (x) = 13 $$

I'm trying to evaluate the general solution for that expression. It reminds me of $5-12-13$ triangle. Since we don't know the degree of $x$, I couldn't proceed further. Specifically, let's take its derivate, which yields

$$\dfrac{d}{dx} 5\cos(x)-12\sin (x) = 13  = 0$$

Comment: What would taking the derivative do? You’re solving an equation, if you have $x+1=2$ and you take the derivative on both sides what does that show??

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/757497/find-4-cos-theta-3-sin-theta-given-that-4-sin-theta-3-cos-theta-5/757498#757498

Comment: @Teh Rod: It is interesting that for this particular type of equation differentiating both sides works: it immediately leads to the solution between $0$ and $2\pi$; $\tan ^{-1}\left(-\frac{12}{5}\right)=-\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{12}{5}\right)$

Comment: You should have written above $$\dfrac{d}{dx} \left( 5\cos(x)-12\sin (x) \right) = \dfrac{d}{dx} (13)  = 0$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**
By Cauchy Schwarz you have
$$169=13^2=(5\cos(x)-12\sin (x))^2 \leq (5^2+12^2)(\cos^2(x)+\sin^2(x))=169$$

Therefore, you must have equality in CS, and hence 
$$\frac{\cos(x)}{5}=\frac{\sin(x)}{-12}$$
Now combine this equality with $$\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)=1$$

Comment: What was the reason you used Cauchy Schwarz? I would like to know that for future questions like this one.

Comment: @Busi I simply recognized that $5,12,13$ is a Pythagorean triple. $$5\cos(x)-12\sin (x) = 13\\5^2+12^2=13^2$$ suggests CS.

Comment: @Busi For the equality case of CS, see one of these questions : https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=cauchy+schwarz+equality

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

For these kind of equations we can use by $t=\tan \frac {x} 2$ with $\frac {x} 2 \neq\frac{\pi}2+k\pi$ (which in that case are not solutions) the following [identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Tangent_half-angle_substitution)

- $\sin (x) =\frac{2t}{1+t^2}$
- $\cos (x) =\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$

to obtain a quadratic equation in $t$ that is

$$5\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}-12\frac{2t}{1+t^2}=13 \iff 9t^2+12t+4=(3t+2)^2=0$$

As an alternative we can also use the following

- $a\sin x+b\cos x=c\sin(x+\varphi)$
- $c = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$
- $\varphi = \operatorname{atan2} \left( b, a \right)$

Comment: Can you explain further what you mean by obtanining a quadratic equation in $t$? I couldn't see any.

Comment: @Busi It's  asimple substitution. I add that

Answer (score 1):

This has a general method: divide the whole equation by $\;\sqrt{5^2+12^2}=13\;$ , so the equation becomes

$$\frac5{13}\cos x-\frac{12}{13}\sin x=1$$

Since $\;\left(\frac5{13}\right)^2+\left(\frac{12}{13}\right)^2=1\;$ , there exists $\;\alpha\in\Bbb R\;$ (in fact, we can choose this value in an infinite number of ways...) such that $\;\cos\alpha=\frac{12}{13}\;,\;\;\sin\alpha=\frac5{13}\;$ , so the equations becomes

$$\sin\alpha\cos x-\sin x\cos\alpha=1\stackrel{\text{trig. identity}}\iff\sin(\alpha-x)=1\ldots$$

Try now to take it from here. And BTW: some high schools specifically forbid to use calculus when solving trigonometric equations!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: the left-hand side is $13\cos (x+\arctan\frac{12}{5})$, so you have to set a cosine to $1$.

Answer (score 0):

The expression $a\cos x+ b\sin x$ can be rewritten as one of

\begin{cases} a\cos x+ b\sin x=r\cos(x-\varphi)\\a \sin x + b \cos x = r\sin(x+\varphi) \end{cases}

where $r=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$, $\varphi=\arctan(b/a)$ if $a>0$, $\varphi=\pi+\arctan(b/a)$ if $a<0$

We use the first equation, $a=5, b=-12$:

$$\sqrt{5^2+12^2}\cos(x-\arctan(-\frac{12}{5}))=13$$

Divide both sides by 13

$$\cos(x-\arctan(-\frac{12}{5}))=1$$

The cos function is only 1 for $n2\pi$, $\arctan(-u)=-\arctan(u)$

$$x+\arctan(12/5)=n2\pi,\quad n\in \mathbb{z}$$

$$\boxed{x=n2\pi-\arctan(\frac{12}{5}),\quad n\in \mathbb{z}}$$