# Evaluating a general solution to $5\cos \theta -12\sin \theta = 13$ using vectors

Tags: trigonometry, vectors, vector-analysis

> Given that
>   $$5\cos \theta -12\sin \theta = 13$$
>   I'm trying to evaluate a general solution for this equation. It appears I'll be using vector product.

My equation is equivalent to

$$\langle (5,12), (\cos\theta, \sin\theta)\rangle = 13$$

which yields (by Cauch Schwarz Inequality)
$$|\langle (5,12), (\cos\theta, \sin\theta)\rangle| \le \|(5,12)\|\|(\cos\theta, \sin\theta)\| = 13$$

This is where I'm stuck.

Regards

Comment: Do you know when the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality is actually an equality?

Comment: @ArnaudD. I truly do not. I'll be very glad if you can show. Even thought I googled it, there were not any useful results. That's what I'm actually missing.

Comment: Wait, you've pretty much asked this question before : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2903190/determining-the-general-solution-for-the-trigonometric-equation-5-cosx-12-si. If you have some trouble with some of the answers there, it's better to comment there.

Comment: @ArnaudD. Yes, that's because I did not get it properly.

Comment: So have you computed the length of each of the vectors?

Comment: I don't think there is any need for a new question. I've added a comment on the other question with a link to questions where the equality case of Cauchy-Schwarz is discussed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that given two vectors in $\mathbb{R^2}$ or $\mathbb{R^3}$ $u$ and $v$ by dot product we have

$$u\cdot v=|u||v|\cos \theta$$

and since $-1\le \cos \theta \le 1$ we have

$$-|u||v|\le u\cdot v\le |u||v|\iff  |u\cdot v|\le |u||v|$$

Since $|\cos \theta|=1$ when $\theta=0, \pi$ the equality holds if and only if $u$ and $v$ are multiple vectors.

The result can be generalized for any dimension and it is known as Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. OP seems to know the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Comment: @ArnaudD. Are you joking? Did you read the aswer of the OP to you own question?: Question: "**Do you know when the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality is actually an equality?**" - Answer: "I truly do not. I'll be very glad if you can show. Even thought I googled it, there were not any useful results. That's what I'm actually missing".

Comment: But your answer did not say anything about when the inequality is an equality, at the time I commented.

Comment: @ArnaudD. Please explain your comment or you have a very short memory or you are in bad faith!

Comment: @ArnaudD. I've answered after your question and after OP answer. I think you should apologize and pay attention to your behaviour before to accuse someone.

Comment: I don't think I should apologize for anything, but now that your answer at least gives the relevant idea, I've retracted my downvote.

Comment: @ArnaudD. I thought it was pretty clear from $u\cdot v=|u||v|\cos \theta$ that equality for  $|u\cdot v|=|u||v||\cos \theta|$  holds for $cos \theta =1$. Anyway after your comment I've added some detail more on that even if you first comment wasn't referring to that point but to the inequality more in general.

Comment: @ArnaudD. You can downvote whenever you like but I can't accept bad faith accusations. If you don't want apologize we can close our discussion here.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.**
\begin{align}
5\cos \theta -12\sin \theta = 13 
&\implies  -12\sin \theta = 13-5\cos \theta
\\
 &\implies  (-12\sin \theta )^2= (13-5\cos \theta)^2
\\
 &\implies  144(1-\cos^2 \theta)= 169-130\cos \theta +\cos^2\theta
\\
 &\implies  144-144\cos^2 \theta= 169-130\cos \theta +\cos^2\theta
\\
&\implies 145\cos^2 \theta-130\cos\theta+25=0
\end{align}