# How would we solve this trigonometric equation using vectors?

Tags: trigonometry, vectors

> $$4\sin\theta +3\cos\theta  = 5$$

How would we solve this trigonometric equation using **vectors**? Since I'm not advanced, I do not truly know where to use vector product.

Regards!

Comment: Can you clarify what particular method you want to use. A simple Google search doesn't seem to yield any obvious candidate.

Comment: Also, you may want to show some if your work or thoughts about the question. Otherwise your post may possibly be downvoted and closed.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/757497/find-4-cos-theta-3-sin-theta-given-that-4-sin-theta-3-cos-theta-5/757498#757498

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your equation is equivalent to $$\langle (3,4), (\cos\theta, \sin\theta)\rangle = 5$$

Cauchy-Schwarz inequality gives 
$$|\langle (3,4), (\cos\theta, \sin\theta)\rangle| \le \|(3,4)\|\|(\cos\theta, \sin\theta)\| = 5$$

so $(3,4)$ and $(\cos\theta, \sin\theta)$ are collinear.
Therefore

$$\tan\theta = \frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta} = \frac43$$ so $\theta= \arctan\frac43 + 2k\pi$ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: It's only a congruence modulo 2π.

Comment: @Bernard True, thanks.

Comment: How did you get that $(3,4)$ and $(\cos\theta, \sin\theta)$ collinear? Can you also specify where I can use this method?

Comment: This step is a bit confusing: $\tan\theta = \frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta} = \frac43$ If you can explain it further, I would be glad. Sorry for asking multiple questions in a row. This may demand an edit.

Comment: @Busi The equality $|\langle x,y\rangle| = \|x\|\|y\|$ in [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) holds if and only if vectors $x,y$ are linearly dependent, i.e. there exists a scalar $\lambda$ such that $y = \lambda x$. Here we get $(\cos\theta, \sin\theta) = \lambda(3,4) = (3\lambda, 4\lambda)$ so $$\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta} = \frac{4\lambda}{3\lambda} = \frac43$$

Comment: @mechanodroid I still didn't get it properly. I wish you explained your calculation further. As stated in the question, I'm not that advanced.

Comment: @Busi Ok, do you know how the inner product and norm are defined? For vectors $(x,y), (x', y') \in \mathbb{R}^2$ we define $\langle (x,y), (x',y')\rangle = xx' + yy'$ and $\|(x,y)\| = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}, \|(x',y')\| = \sqrt{x'^2 + y'^2}$. The Cauchy-Schwarz inequality states that $$|\langle (x,y), (x',y')\rangle| \le \|(x,y)\|\|(x', y')\|$$ and $$|\langle (x,y), (x',y')\rangle| = \|(x,y)\|\|(x', y')\| \text{ if and only if } \exists \lambda \in \mathbb{R} \text{ such that } (x', y') = \lambda(x,y)$$

Comment: I noticed that if $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$ is such that $4\sin\theta +3\cos\theta  = 5$, then $$|\langle (3,4), (\cos\theta, \sin\theta)\rangle| = 5 = \|(3,4)\|\|(\cos\theta, \sin\theta)\|$$ so the equality condition above implies that $\exists \lambda\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $(\cos\theta, \sin\theta) = \lambda(3,4)$.

Comment: @mechanodroid Can I apply your method to kinda trigonometric equations?

Comment: @Busi This one was pretty much ad hoc, but you can try it whenever you can write your equality in terms of inner products and norms.