# Compute the intersection of the offsets of two tangents between two circles

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, coordinate-systems

Pardon the amateurish notation and what's probably a very simple puzzle for most on this site. Still, the solution eludes me....

I have 3 circles $C_R, C_G, C_B$ as shown in the diagram. I know the $x$ and $y$ coords of each circle's center, as well as their respective radii, $r_R, r_G, r_B$.

I am looking for the formula to compute the *x* and *y* coords of the purple point **F** in terms of the 3 circles' *x*, *y* and *r*.

[image: Diagram]

**F** is derived from:

1. finding the tangents between 1) $C_R$ and $C_G$ and 2) $C_R$ and $C_B$,
2. offsetting each tangent by 1) $r_G$ and 2) $r_B$
3. computing the intersection **F** of the two offset lines

(A potentially simplifying assumption here is that $C_G$ and $C_B$ are horizontally aligned, ie their centers always have the same *x* coordinate)

Comment: The only difficult step is 1). You can see here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/211538/common-tangent-to-two-circles

Comment: What steps you do not know how to do? Are you interested in all twelve solutions?

Comment: Step 1 is not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WLOG, we can assume that R is at (0, 0). I also assume that the equation of $L$, the external tangent to $C_R$ and $C_G$ can be found.

[image]

The green dotted circle (called $C_H$) is the translated image of $C_G$ so that it touches $C_R$ internally at $S$. The same can be done to $C_B$.

Clearly, $F = (h, y_B)$, where $y_B$ is known and $h$ has to be determined.

$RM = y_M$, a known quantity which is given by $M(0, y_M)$, the point of intersection of $L$ and $x = 0$. Note that $RS = r_R$ is also a known quantity. Then, $\theta$ in $\triangle RSM$ can be found via $\cos \theta = \dfrac {r_R}{y_M}$.

$RH (= r_R - r_G)$, $RP$ and $PJ$ can also be subsequently found. Finally, $h = - (RP + PJ)$.

Comment: Thank you for that! I already upvoted, but I need a bit of time to digest this solution. Thanks again. I'll be back....

Comment: @meetamit You are welcome. Do ask if I jump too fast.