# Common Tangent to Two Non Intersecting Circles

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, circles, coordinate-systems

If the equations of two non intersecting circles are given in the general form i.e. $$x^2 + y^2 + 2gx +2fy + c =0$$ and $$x^2 + y^2 + 2g'x +2f'y + c' =0$$ , then how can I find common tangents on these circles. I am not able to figure out an approach for this. Also, what would be the lengths of these tangents

Comment: @abiessu It would be much appreciated if i can get information on all four. But it's alright if you just give me a standard approach for finding them 

Comment: Maybe easier to work with the form $(x-h)^2+(y-k)^2=r^2$ for the circles.

Comment: @coffeemath ok. So can u please show me the approach for that. I am taking the general form because it is used in many questions, but that can be easily converted into this format. Thanks

Comment: A possible approach: find the centers and the radii of such circles. With such info, you may easily find the interior and the exterior homothetic centers. The tangents through that points are the four common tangents.

Comment: As an alternative, take the equation of a generic line and impose that is is tangent to both circles. That is equivalent to stating that two discriminants vanish at the same time.

Comment: have a look at (http://math.stackexchange.com/q/211538)