# I can't find the equation of common tangents to these two circles in the 2-d plane .

Tags: geometry

What are the equations of the tangents common to the circles x² + y²=1 , and (x-1)² + (y-3)² = 4?

I first used the T²=SS1 form which gives the joint equation of two tangents to a curve dream from an external point , but the equation of becoming too complex to solve ,please help me out .
Thank you

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4057527/what-are-the-equations-of-the-tangents-common-to-the-circles-x2-y2-1-and

Comment: Looks like a popular question.

Comment: The unit circle is self-dual, the other circle has dual $5y^2+6xy+6y-3x^2+2x+1=0.$ The four intersections of the duals give the four common tangents: $0x-y+1=0,x+0y+1=0,-\frac45 x+\frac35 y+1=0,-\frac35 x-\frac45 y +1=0.$

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/211538/common-tangent-to-two-circles/4057624#4057624

Comment: Thanks a lot !!! Jan-Magnus Økland , buy what is DUAL ??Please tell me .

Comment: Since you asked, the [dual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_curve) when the conic has matrix $M$ is the conic given by the inverse (or more generally the adjoint) matrix. The dual curve parametrizes the tangents to the curve, and common tangents therefore correspond to the intersection points of the duals. A point in the dual plane corresponds via the correspondence $x X_i+y Y_i+1=0,$ where $(X_i,Y_i)$ are the intersection points of the duals.

Comment: BTW if you @ me I get a notification.

Comment: Thanks @Jan-MagnusØkland , you are really helpful !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick sketch will show you that lines $x=-1$ and $y=1$ are two common tangents. The other two tangents are the reflections of these about the line through the centres.

Comment: Thanks !!!!!!! I appreciate it , it's such a intuitive and quick way of solving this problem !!